# How much cash will I need to build three complete houses?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I've finally "completed" Skyrim and I am about to download the Hearthfire DLC.

I will want to unlock the "Master Architect" achievement but I would like to do it in pretty much one go; that is, without having to go off and make more money.

So my question is - How much cash will I need for the three plots of land and then the three homes with all wings and cellars, etc?

I think I've got about $200k on me.  Will this be enough?

Comment: Its not just a money commitment - you need large amounts of other materials (iron for hinges, stone for walls, wood planks for like everything), and you can't exactly buy unlimited quantities of all of the listed. Also, each for each wing, there are up to three options for what to build there, each with differing material costs

Comment: Smithing material is going to be your major limiting factor, since you simply can't buy enough of it in one city for a whole house (even if unfurnished).  You can forget remotely getting close to furnishing everything.  Building those 10 safes in the basement takes a huge amount of Steel, nevermind the obscure material needed for the altars, all the god's necklaces that you can't buy, random alchemy components, etc.

Comment: I have a chest in Whiterun that is brimming with smithing materials.  It's like a B&Q store in there!  I'm looking forward to this DLC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to do some questing to earn the rights to purchase the plots.  But the Plots will cost 5000 each.  As part of the purchase price the plot will already have an anvil, lumber pile and a chest with enough material to build an unfurnished Small House.

Sawn Logs cost 10 each.  You'll need 17 for the Small House/Entryway (included in the price of the plot), 47 for the Main Hall and 14/18/24 (depending on wing choice) for each of the 3 wings.  This is the only other cost that is unavoidable.

Stone & Clay can be mined on site for just time & effort.  You can also pay your steward to buy them for you, though I can't imagine why you'd want to.

Lastly you'll need Iron & Corundum to make hinges, locks, and iron fittings (for the doors) and *lots* of nails.  Whether you purchase these or mine them yourself is your choice.

All in all 200K G should be more than enough if you don't purchase *all* of the required materials.

---

Notes:

- For the purposes of the achievement, no furnishings are required, but, FWIW, this is another case of either handing cash to your steward or gathering/assembling yourself.
- Wings with sloped roofs (the 18 log group) only require you to make hardware for 2 doors instead of 3, due to a lack of 2nd story access.
- If your "completion" of Skyrim includes a rebuilt Thieves' Guild, then consider visiting Riften for your Ore/Ingot needs.  There's a Smith in town and 3 in The Flagon.

Comment: Don't forget, you can go to a mill yourself for the logs if you are friendly and go during 'business hours' and 'use' the logging platform. Just talk to the mill NPC (there are several mills) and ask if you can use it.